# Failed retrieving file while installing lamp on Archlinux with VB

Tags: installation, virtualbox, lamp, archlinux

i'm trying to install lamp on Archlinux and i'm using VirtualBox for it.

after typing "sudo pacman -S apache" and "y" after the promp asks to proceed for installation this happens

> :: Retrieving packages ....
>
> error failed retrieving file 'apr-1.5.1-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.polymorf.fr

I tried googling but i could not find any similar problems.

Using the latest version of VBox and Archlinux as of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As archlinux.polymorf.fr seems to be up-to-date mirror (you always can check at https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/), and apr-1.5.1-1 is the current version of a package, it seems that problem is on your side.

You can check free disk space with `df -h /var` (packages are stored in /var/cache/pacman/pkg).

If the partition is full, you can remove old packages with `pacman -Scc`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: We just changed some dhcp setting from a fix found on the archlinux forum and it started working.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that network was functioning, and something else caused the problem.